# Adding count of features in categories to legend using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, symbology, legend

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop and I would like to know How to add the Count (which is visible on the Symbology tab of the Layer Properties dialog) to the legend?

[image: Layer Properties]